# Is the second 'T' silent in "petites" ?

Tags: prononciation, liaisons

In [this video](https://youtu.be/pF0d0gt9u-w?t=40s), around the 0:41 mark, the man speaking pronounces *petites* with the second *t* lost to a liaison. Is that a regional affectation, or did I just never know this? If this is standard, what is the rule that causes that to be silent?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The man actually pronounces the second t. Even though it is not as clear as the sounds from the beginning of the word, I distinctly hear it. If you play the video at half-speed, you can hear it being merged with the z sound of the s liaison, PETI-tZanimations.

In standard French, the t in that phrase is not silent.

Comment: Exactly, on the contrary in those cases the e is always muted.

Comment: @Walfrat You got me thinking : most of the time in casual conversation the e is muted but I'm not entirely sure it is a strict rule. I have a song in mind where it clearly is not muted : "Petite Marie by Francis Cabrel". Altough it might be an artistic decision.

Comment: @Benoittr: singing and poetry are a special case.

Comment: The e would be pronounced by most speakers in contexts like « petite housse ».

Answer (score 10):

The second /t/ is not lost. It's there, but it merges with the following /s/ (which, itself, is voiced into a /z/ because of the intervocalic context). So in the end you have /pətitzanimasjɔ̃/.

Answer (score 2):

With the e (or es as here) at the end, the t is pronounced, maybe not forcefully, but still there. as already stated, the liaison is more between the s and the following a, so the t sort of gets lost.

Answer (score 1):

***I did not watch the video.***

It depends. In French, the masculine form of the word is petit (no e at the end). In this case, if the word after "petit" starts with vowel, the "t" would be pronounced (i.e. un petit arbre). If the word after "petit" begins with a consonant, the "t" would be silent (i.e. un petit gateau).

The feminie version (petite) does not have this peculiarity, since there is always a vowel (petit**e**) after it.